# Should I increase buffer size to improve performance when making repeated GET requests?

Tags: c#, http, stream, httpwebresponse

I'm writing a .NET program in C# that makes GET requests and downloads pages to parse - a sort of crawler. I noticed that it has to read from the stream multiple times to download each page because each page is so large.

Currently I've set my stream buffer size to 5024 bytes. My question is would it be more efficient to increase this size and therefore perform less stream reads? Or is it better to process less data at a time from which to parse?

Basically worded differently - is it quicker to parse more data at once and have to call stream.read less often, or the other way around?

Thanks!

Comment: If it was 1024 initially, it would have made more sense to change it to 2048, 8192 or some other nice round number. But why don't you simply profile it? Change it to 64k and measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, generally, increasing the size of the buffer and fitting more data in at a time would increase the speed of the operation, the performance increase is going to be minimal at best. I think instead what you want to try is an asynchronous request. Something like
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx). This allows the application to employ the thread pool to read from the socket or multiple simultaneously and then work on the stream only when there is something to be worked on. This frees up the application to do other things as the data is being pulled into the buffer.

Comment: I have never worked with asynchronous operations and this is my first attempt at a multi threaded app so please excuse me if I sound ignorant... What I was hoping to do is use split threads - one pool for downloading into a queue a list of the url's which need to be parsed, and one pool for downloading and parsing the url's in the queue. Without asynchronous calls, is this possible?

Comment: @user1115071 It is absolutely possible. However it will not be efficient. The thread that is downloading the web page will block until the page is fully downloaded and then move on to the parsing. Your slowdown, I suspect, is not in your buffer, its in the fact that download the page synchronously makes the thread completely stop. However, to accomplish what you are looking for, simply write two separate functions that do the two different pieces of work and have some shared object between them. You would start the threads like "Thread t1 = new Thread(function1name); t1.start();"